# I'm in the middle of Tachanun when they take out the Torah; what do I do?

Tags: torah-service, hefsek-interruption, tachanun, standing-sitting, nusach-ashkenaz

This happens to me a lot on Mondays and Thursdays:  I'm just putting down my head to finish Tachanun when the baal tefilah says kaddish, the aron is opened and the Torah is taken out.  Do I stop what I'm doing? Stand up? Answer "amen" and "y'he shmei rabba" to the kaddish?  Say "vay'he binsora"?  Or should I continue with Tachanun until I'm done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Siach Tefila question 137 & 138](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=47713&st=&pgnum=462&hilite=) indicates as follows. If one is in the midst of the actual Tachanun (the part where you place your head on your arm) then he should finish the Tachanun, however if one is in any other part then he should stop and say Vayehi Bin'soa.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the actual Tachanun" and "finish the Tachanun"? You seem to be saying that if your head is down, you finish the part where your head is down. Or do you mean finish even the part where you sit up again and the part where you stand up at the end?

Comment: Yes, I realize it's not your Teshuvah, and it's vague. Just curious how you interpret it.

Comment: You finish the part where your head is down

Comment: @Gershon Gold:  What about the kaddish before opening the aron?

Comment: I did not see anywhere, however I am pretty certain you would stop for Kadish if you stop to say say Vayehi Bin'soa

Comment: It is not clear from the wording whether he means שלא יפסיק בדברים or whether he means that you should actually remain seated and continue tachanun while the Torah is being carried, despite the fact that one *must* stand in the presence of a sefer Torah that is being moved (see Sh"A YD 282:2, MB 146:17). I suspect that he means the former, contrary to your answer.