# Catching Up When Saying Tachanun M/Th

Tags: tefilla, torah-reading, priorities, hefsek-interruption, tachanun

On Mondays and Thursdays I often fall very behind during tachanun. I see two options — I can start with the congregation after having listened with proper intent during chazarat hashatz, or I can start during chazarat hashatz and finish so I can pay attention during the Torah reading.

To complicate matters, my custom is to stand with feet together (as I would during my own prayer) during chazarat hashatz so as to be yotzei the Rav's understanding of the Rambam, that there is a separate mitzvah of tefillat hatzibbur b'tzibbur. Starting tachanun early would interrupt that.

If I did start early, would I continually interrupt my V'hu rachum with "baruch hu uvaruch shmo" and "amein" for each bracha, or just interrupt for modim or just birchat kohanim?

Related: [I'm in the middle of Tachanun when they take out the Torah; what do I do?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/23490/1362)

Comment: I always have this problem davening in a Chabad minyan but trying to say the Ashkenaz version of Tachanun on M/Th

Comment: @Daniel to make matters even worse, I say vidui before tachanun (though the minyan doesn't) so I fall even further behind, but if I started earlier I would be visibly interrupting davening.

Comment: There's a third option: say less of Tachanun with more kavana.

Comment: @DoubleAA if that is indeed an option, are there guildelines?

Comment: @Dan Not sure. See [OC 1:4](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%90#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.93). I don't know if it applies here, but I'd say it's reasonable enough to be an option in the _hava amina_ of a question.

Comment: @DoubleAA as advice it might apply but without specific guidelines, I'm still lost. What are me'at tachanunim vs. the whole thing?

Comment: My understanding (need to find sources) is that nothing overrules listening to chazaratz hashatz: not talmud torah, not catching up on skipped prayers and not starting new ones early. obviously if you havent yet done shema amida and zman is approaching then that takes precedence