# Which parts of Tachnun to skip

Tags: halacha, tachanun

In one of the Shuls that I Daven they often say Tachnun so quickly (especially Monday & Thursday) that by the time they say Kaddish I am still way behind. If one finds himself in such a situation is there a preferred list of what to say and what to skip? Or should one just fall behind?

Comment: I can't provide a source o I'll leave this as a comment -- in our school, we have the students just say the first v'hu rachum paragraph and then jump to nefillas apayim.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/28020/catching-up-when-saying-tachanun-m-th

Comment: And an answer with a source: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/23493/3483

Answer (score 3):

[See this](http://rabbikaganoff.com/the-significance-of-vehu-rachum/) - You're not the 1st person to have asked this.
Excerpt:

> **Is it more important to say Vehu Rachum or to say Tachanun?**
>
> What happens if there is insufficient time to recite both Vehu Rachum
>   and the rest of the Tachanun together with the tzibur?
>
> It seems that one should recite Tachanun with the tzibur and “Vehu
>   Rachum” after davening.
>
> It should be noted that the commentaries dispute what is included in
>   the takanah of reciting Vehu Rachum. Some contend that the takanah is
>   to say Vehu Rachum, and to say it while standing (Shulchan Aruch,
>   Orach Chayim 134:1), whereas others explain that the takanah included
>   only reciting Vehu Rachum, but did not require one to stand (Levush).
>   (They all agree, however, that one should recite Vehu Rachum while
>   standing.)
>
> Vehu Rachum should be treated with the kedusha of the Shemoneh Esrei
>   (Magen Avraham). Therefore, there are those who contend that it should
>   be said quietly (Rama 134:1). However, the Beis Yosef rules that one
>   may say Vehu Rachum aloud, as is the custom of many people.

Comment: I would love this answer more if they supplied a source for it.