# Skipping Paragraphs in long Tachanun

Tags: sources-mekorot, tefilla, tachanun

Although it pains me to ask the question, after davening in many orthodox shuls throughout New York, New Jersey, and Maryland, it seems chazanim often skip parts of והוא רחום (longer Monday/Thursday Tachanun) based on the time it takes to say it. Is there a source to allow for such a leniency?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/88559/13811

Comment: Check out Shulchan Arukh Siman 1

Comment: There are multiple versions of the extended tachanun prayer. For example, the version in Nusach Sefard is much shorter than the version in Nusach Ashkenaz.

Comment: Curious - considering that in most places the long tachanun is said silently, how do you know that so many chazanim are skipping paragraphs? Perhaps they are just speed daveners?

Comment: @DanF Completely agree with your question as I assumed every chazan was just fast, but- multiple conversations this week led me to believe there are quite a number of chazanim skipping words/paragraphs to maintain the regular speed

Comment: Cf https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71138/170 , https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10268/170

Comment: I pray in a "40 minutes" _nusach sefard_ minyan, but it's the only one close enough. I arrive there 20 minutes earlier, so we finish roughly in the same time. Although on Mondays/Thursdays usually I have to stop around הפותח יד, and I recuperate the rest when the Torah was put back to the ark...

Comment: I daven in a school minyan and apparently someone spoke to someone who got a heter to the effect that we can say part of the long tachanun (so that the students say something). I think that this was intended to be "say part Monday and the rest on Thursday" but I don't know -- I just know that the end result is that we say less and that someone, somewhere asked and got an answer.

Comment: It's not as much as "every chazzan is fast" but more that the cong. and frequently the rav requests him to "move it". I understand that for weekdays. I don't get it for Shabbat except for *haskama* minyanim.

Comment: Is it a must to say Tachanun?

Comment: @rosends I see a huge difference between abridging davening in a school setting for the sake of chinuch and abridging davening in a normal minyan setting for the sake of a quicker davening - one encourages davening, the other defeats its own purpose.